# How to install plistlib in python3 virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, plistlib

I've created a Python 3 virtual environment, and I am trying to install the plistlib package.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
(venv) venv$pip install --upgrade plistlib
Collecting plistlib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plistlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for plistlib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`plistlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html) module is within the standard libraries. You don't need to install it, it will be available for import in your existing Python 3 installation.